# Cucumber: Does a Background run before each execution of a Scenario Outline?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Given a Feature file like the following:

```
Feature: Coffee improves mood in the background

  Background:
    Given the user drank coffee

  Scenario Outline: Coffee changes peoples moods
    Then user <USER> should be <MOOD>

    Examples:
      | USER     | MOOD         |
      |  Michael |  happy       |
      |  Elvis   |  electrified |
      |  John    |  sad         |
```

Should the background test step "the user drank coffee" run 1 time, or 3 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the contrived answer below.  In the output, you'll see that the background step is executed 3 times.

feature.rb:

```
Feature: Does a background run before each scenario outline?

  Background:
    When I'm a background step

  Scenario Outline: foo
    Then I should print '<count>'

    Examples:
      |count|
      | 10  |
      | 20  |     
      | 30  |
```

step_def.rb:

```
When(/^I'm a background step$/) do
  print "BACKGROUND EXECUTED"
end

Then(/^I should print '(\d+)'$/) do |num|
  # empty step
end
```

output:

```
Feature: Does a background run before each scenario outline

BACKGROUND EXECUTED  Background:                  # features/login.feature:3
    When I'm a background step # features/step_definitions/login.rb:1

  Scenario Outline: foo           # features/login.feature:6
    Then I should print '<count>' # features/login.feature:7

    Examples:
      | count |
      | 10    |
BACKGROUND EXECUTED      | 20    |
BACKGROUND EXECUTED      | 30    |

3 scenarios (3 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. And best of all, now this phenomenon is documented!